# SWIG for JavaScript: "Module did not self-register." on load

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig

With SWIG 3.0.12 and node 8.12.0 I want to create a native module from some minimal code base:

**`api.h`**:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
std::string foo();
```

**`api.cpp`**:

```
#include "api.h"
std::string foo() {
  return "hello world";
}
```

**`api.i`**:

```
%module(directors="1") api
%{
#include <api.h>
%}
%include "api.h"
```

to build the node-module I run:

```
swig -c++ -javascript -node api.i
g++ -c -fPIC api_wrap.cxx api.cpp  -I /usr/include/node -I .
g++ -shared *.o -o api.node
```

.. and try to import it:

```
node -e "api = require('./api.node');"
```

But now I get

```
module.js:682
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:682:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at [eval]:1:7
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
```

I found lot's of questions and answers regarding similar errors but they all seem to be related to `npm` and incorrect versions of node modules and the node runtime.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: My naive guess would be the path to the library you want to add (`./api.node`). Have you tried to use full path instead of `./`?

Comment: Yes, checked that already - in case the module can't be found the error message is `Error: Cannot find module '/home/me/path/to/api.node.nonexist'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current release of `swig` (3.0.12) does not support Node.js versions 7 or later. Instead, you get compile-time errors like `error: no template named 'WeakCallbackData' in namespace 'v8'`

To use `swig` with Node 8, either use the master branch, a later version of `swig` (it looks like this will be fixed in the next release, which will likely be 3.0.13), or download the 4 files changed in [PR 968](https://github.com/swig/swig/pull/968/files) and install them in place of the ones that came with `swig 3.0.12`. On my Mac, those files are in `/usr/local/Cellar/swig/3.0.12/share/swig/3.0.12/javascript/v8/`

After that, though, @frans still has some work to do.

According to the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Javascript.html#Javascript_node_extensions), "it is crucial to compile your module using the same compiler flags as used for building v8", for which they recommend building your module with `node-gyp`.

You need to create a `binding.gyp` like this:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "api",
      "sources": [ "api.cpp", "api_wrap.cxx" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and then, after creating the wrapper with `swig`, build the module with

```
 node-gyp configure build
```

(If necessary, install `node-gyp` with `npm install -g node-gyp`)

You probably also do not want `%module(directors="1")` for JavaScript, and you should not use the bracket style `include <file.h>` for your own header files.

Also, if you want to use `std::string`, you need to include `std_string.i` in your interface file.

I suggest your `api.i` would be better as

```
%module api
%{
#include "api.h"
%}

%include "std_string.i"
%include "api.h"
```

Finally, when you are done, the module will be in `./build/Release`, so test with

```
node -e "api = require('./build/Release/api.node'); console.log(api.foo());"
```

Comment: I did everything you said () and in the end it worked (which is fine) but strangely it works now with version 3.0.12 of SWIG as well..